# Persist Facebook bundle for later reuse

Tags: android, facebook

I have a login with Facebook implemented in an application. I need to do relogin every 10 minutes so I want to save Facebook `Bundle` to reuse it on this scheduled relogin. How to persist a `Bundle` so not to force users to relogin manually?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of first login, set the current `Session` as active `Session` ->

```
Session.setActiveSession(session);  //session - your current session object
```

Override `onSavedInstanceState` of Activity LifeCyle like this->

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Save current session
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Session.saveSession(session, outState);
}
```

Now next time when you want to login again just use->

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
```

You will get logged in `Session`, now you can use this `Session` for performing your tasks.